# Form Validation not hitting function call

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I'm not sure why my async function is not firing after my form is valid. I am hitting the print statement. Any clues as to why?

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: (() {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        print('Form is Valid');
        () async {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = true;
          });
          await signIn();
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        };
        return;
      }
    }),
    child: !isLoading
        ? Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue[500],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 65.0, vertical: 15),
              child: Text(
                'Sign in',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
),
```

I tried messing with my form validator, I expect to be able to hit the `setState()` bloc just fine but I am not, it seems to stop just before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating inline-function which syntax is

```
(){
 /// yourTask
}()
```

You are missing calling the function. And it is unnecessary to nested code, you can do

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
      final bool isValided = _formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;
      if (isValided) {
        print('Form is Valid');
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
        await signIn();
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: Glad to help, more about [function](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts)